# Negation of statements - Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

How to write and proof of the following statement?

If n is positive number and not negative - than 5n + 3 is even number, only if n is odd number.

Here is my trial:

If p is positive number

$\forall n (P(n) \land \neg P(n) \rightarrow Q(n)) \rightarrow R(n)$

Comment: negation of (a or b) is equal to (negation a and negation b)

Comment: "It is not true that..."

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  This community greatly appreciates knowing what you have tried, and where you get stuck. For example, are you able to translate the sentence without the negation?  So please add a little more to your post. Thanks!

Comment: The statement is of the form: "If $\sf P$, then $\sf Q$, only if $\sf R$."  Write this nested conditional in a purely symbolic representation, apply your negation rules, then translate back. Show us what you get and we will check it for you.

Comment: @Bram28 Thank you! I actually don' t need negation. I made edits and also added my trial.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you! That's helpful, I just added my trial. Could you take a look? I'm not sure if i need to write that's not negative number part...

Comment: @Nanina Can you also please add what P, Q, and R stand for? Also, you should consult the mathjax tutorilal that shows you how to typeset mathematical formulas.  I'll do this one for you, so you can take a look at that.

Comment: I will look at mathjax tutorial! Thanks so much for the edits!

Comment: PS: If a number is positive then it is *also* not negative.  ($0$ is the only integer that is neither positive nor negative.)

Comment: PPS: If you don't need the negation, you should change the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > If n is positive number and not negative , then 5n + 3 is even number, only if n is odd number.
>
> Here is my trial:
>
> If p is positive number
>
> $\forall n (P(n) \land \neg P(n) \rightarrow Q(n)) \rightarrow R(n)$

Well, you have the nesting correct.   You should also embrace the entire scope of the quantifier, since implication have precedence.

If $P(n)$ means "$n$ is positive", then $\neg P(n)$ means "$n$ is *not* positive."    You need an additional predicate.

$\forall n\left({\left({\left({P(n)\wedge \neg S(n)}\right)\to Q(n)}\right)\to R(n)}\right)$ where $P(n):= (n>0) \\ S(n):=(n<0) \\ Q(n):= (2\mid (5n+3)) \\ R(n):= (2\nmid n)$

However, $P(n)\wedge\neg S(n)$ is redundant.   You really just need to specify $P(n)$

$$\forall n\left(\raise{1pt}{\left({P(n)\to Q(n)}\right)\to R(n)}\right)\\ \forall n\left({\left({(n>0)\to (2\mid (5n+3))}\right)\to (2\nmid n)}\right)$$

To evaluate the truth of this statement either:

- use implication equivalence
- evaluate the falsity the negation